# ¿Porque se recomienda utilizar métodos getter y setter en TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, método

Cómo están? Estoy empezando a aprender JavaScript luego de venir de Python durante mucho tiempo. Y en 2 cursos que estoy tomando de TypeScript, recomiendan la creación de los métodos Getters y Setters cuando creamos una clase, dicen que como typescript es más orientado a objetos se recomiendan, pero realmente no los veo necesarios si siempre se transpila a javascript, podemos obviarlos ya acceder y setear atributos sin necesidad de esos métodos.

Bien mi duda es... en casos simples porque usarlos??? Me refiero a que recomiendan que por cada atributo del objeto se cree un get y un set pero realmente no le encuentro el sentido.

Ya que si por ejemplo yo creo la clase choche voy a asignarle un get y un set a color así no hago tan largo el código pero en los cursos que estoy tomando de 2 profesores diferentes ambos generan los get y set para todos los atributos.

```
class Coche {
  public color: string;
  public modelo: string;
  public velocidad: number;

  public getColor() {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public setColor(color: string) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

Bien supongamos que quiero asignarle un color y tomar un color de una instancia de esa clase

```
coche1 = new Coche();

// Ahora le agrego el color
coche1.setColor("Amarillo");

// y para tomar el color
console.log(coche1.getColor());

// Bien pero en realidad me resulta mucho más simple hacerlo así y consigo lo mismo
coche1.color = "Amarillo";
console.log(choche1.color);
```

Entonces realmente no le encuentro el sentido en a los getters y setters, para mí complican más la escritura de código y tal vez un poco la lectura.

Podría alguno explicarme mejor la necesidad o el porque recomiendan el uso de estos métodos en TypeScript?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: por que typescript es mas orientado a objetos, javascript es multiparadigma

Comment: Si entiendo eso, ahora lo voy a agregar a la pregunta principal, pero lo que no entiendo porque los métodos getter y setter, si en realidad no son necesarios para asignar y tomar los atributos de las clases. Realmente no crees que ensucian el código más que limpiarlo?

Comment: no es que lo ensucien simplemente dentro de una arquitectura OOP, tenemos a la clase como el entorno global que a su vez tiene métodos de funcionalidad o de asignación como en este caso es asignar un valor a una propiedad y después tomar el valor de dicha propiedad; por ejemplo cuando haces la instanciación.

Comment: Osea que es más que nada para cumplir más fielmente con el paradigma de la programación orientada a opbjetos. Pero en realidad en el caso de JavaScript no es realmente necesario. De todas formas quiero dejar claro que me parece una razon más que suficiente el utilizar los métodos para cumplir con la arquitectura orientada a objetos. Aunque realmente esperaba que en este caso me brindaran algún beneficio al utilizarlo además de cumplir con las reglas jaja.

Comment: @ViggoMortredSen sin esas funciones como harias el paso de por referencia y paso de parametros?

Comment: @x-rw en cuanto al paso de valores por referencia en el ejemplo que yo plantee no es necesario, ya que justamente es lo que aquí planteo, al usar setColor(color); no estoy referenciando al espacio de memoria que ocupa la instancia en el parámetro, lo que estoy haciendo es enviando el nuevo valor. entiendo que hay muchos métodos que cumplen funcionalidades diferentes, pero me parece que por ej. en este caso getcolor y setcolor es solo para seguir una convención porque el valor puedo leerlo o asignarlo apuntando directamente al atributo del objeto coche1.color.

Comment: @ViggoMortredSen si haces eso que dijiste ultimo 'objeto coche1.color.' estarias rompiendo el principio de encapsulacion

Comment: @x-rw Exactamente a eso me refiero! justamente la utilización en TypeScripts es para seguir principios pero no porque en la transpilación a JavaScript generan alguna mejora en el código final transpilado. Simplemente la utilización de getters y setters es para mantener el principio de encapsulación y que todo lo que tenga que ver con un objeto esté dentro del mismo.

Comment: @ViggoMortredSen bien creo que es asunto solucionado, deberia poner mi respuesta?

Comment: No tengo claro los motivos que dais en esta discusión, hay otros lenguajes como Python donde no se usan generalmente getters y setters. Si no se hace ninguna validación en esos métodos, un setter o getter no aporta nada más que seguir una convención, pero no afecta al encapsulamiento

Answer (score 5):

Es cierto que en un pequeño proyecto en un fichero simple la practica de Getters y Setter no tiene mucha logica, sin embargo en grandes proyectos o ficheros el uso de estos metodos  te otorga una **organización,seguridad y previsión** hacia el proyecto.
**EJEMPLOS de utilidad**

- Supongamos que tienes los atributos `temperatura1` y `temperatura2` 
  pero solo un setter `setTemperatura1()`:

  ```
  public temperatura1: int;
  public temperatura2: int;

  public setTemperatura1(temperatura:int){
      this.temperatura = temperatura;
  }
  ```

  Pasa algo de tiempo y a lo largo del codigo, se establecen cientos de veces estos atributos. De repente alguien hace una pregunta `En que estamos poniendo los grados? El cliente solicito que fuera en farenheit.`

  Que es lo que ocurre ahora???

   Para `temperatura1` basta con hacer un pequeño cambio en su Setter:

  ```
  public setTemperatura1(temperatura:int){
       this.temperatura = temperatura*1.8+32;
  }
  ```

  Y ya esta todo solucionado, sin embargo para `temperatura2` hace falta ir a cada una de esas lineas de código escritas previamente a hacer el cambio
- Tu equipo esta desarrollando una app en la que estáis varios y tenéis la clase `coche` que has mencionado anteriormente:

  ```
  class Coche {
    public color: string;
    public modelo: string;
    public velocidad: number;
  }
  ```

  Avanzais en el proyecto estableciendo directamente los atributos `Coche.velocidad=200;`

   Estais haciendo un filtrado de coches por velocidad y la aplicación ha petado, un dato es mal introducido, ni idea de cual, pero encima  tienes miles de modelos de coches, vas a ponerte a comprobar la información coche por coche? Cuanto tardas en solucionar el porblema?

  Que ha pasado realmente?? Alguien se le fue y había introducido una velocidad negativa en alguna parte del código y otro un numero entero.
  No te gustaría tener un forma de tratar eso?

  ```
  class Coche {
    private color: string;
    private modelo: string;
    private velocidad: number;

    public setVelocidad(velocidad: int){
      this.velocidad = Math.abs(velocidad);
    }
  }
  ```

  De esta forma tienes asegurado que solo números absolutos sean establecido, es decir tienes control sobre los valores que se introducen en tus atributos

---

Al final depende de cada uno es solo una buena practica el hacerlo y en códigos pequeños puede parecer trabajo de mas pero en grandes proyectos al final te estas ahorrando mucho trabajo en cuestiones de trata de errores,seguridad en el codigo, gestion del codigo y rapidez de cambio o ajustes por solo acostumbrarte a utilizar un getter o setter

Comment: Mi profesor nos exige que todos los ejercicios realizados tengan getters y setters, así, porque sí, y creo que ese es uno de los motivos por los que aprender java se me ha complicado tanto, la mayoría de los ejercicios elaborados se harían muchísimo más sencillos sin POO pero visto de esa manera que lo planteas tiene bastante sentido, muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 4):

Son lenguajes diferentes por lo que deberías de utilizar la forma de programar en Typescript, la cual casi siempre utilizar la notación **.** para acceder a las propiedades, por lo que utilizar getter y setters en un lenguaje que ya te permite acceder y asignar sus propiedades me parece mas trabajo del necesario.

Para que los getters y setters tengan sentido tendrías que tener todas tus propiedades privadas.

```
export class Hero {
   private _id: number;

   set id(id: number) {
      this._id = id;
   }

   get id(){
        return this._id;
   }
}

Hero h = new Hero();
// Getter
var myId = h.id;

// Setter
h.id = 1;
```

Sin utilizar getters y setters.

```
export class Hero {
   id: number;
}

Hero h = new Hero();
// Getter
const id = h.id;
// Setter
h.id = 2;
```

Seria como utilizar en C# getter y setters en metodos en vez de hacerlo en las propiedades con en **{ get; set; }** (hay otras) por simplemente utilizar un estilo basado en *java*.

**Al final el que decide como escribir el codigo eres tu, y si crees que es la mejor forma pues adelante.**

Edito para dejarte un texto de [@SeanMiddleditch](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/87t1h7/are_getters_and_setters_an_antipattern/dwgnvvd/) en Reddit.

> Just to start with the biggest items: using a getter/setter function
>   breaks core JavaScript/TypeScript language features, like object
>   property enumeration or destructuring, as well as various higher-order
>   functional programming patterns. Using properties where possible makes
>   your code work with the rest of the language better.
>
> More abstractly around the topic of getters and setters, note that
>   it's common for developers to have a strong expectation when seeing
>   `setFoo(x)` or `getFoo()` that these are *cheap* and *efficient*
>   functions. If they're doing anything else, a good style guide would
>   recommend that they be named appropriate to strongly indicate what
>   they're going to do. Treat functions as verbs: if the function doesn't
>   just get a value, it shouldn't be called `get`.
>
> In a language without properties, one could argue that a getter
>   function signifies that there *might* be bad code involved. It's a
>   hint of potential dragons. That's just not true in JS/TS though
>   because property getters are a thing; there simply is no strong
>   guarantee that any `x.foo` isn't evil, so we have to check (or trust
>   our libraries) rather than relying on syntactic warning signs.
>
> Getter functions are sometimes just used for consistency in some
>   languages. There's no easy standard way to have a read-only public
>   field on a non-const object in C++ for example, so maintaining proper
>   encapsulation around a field that has value constraints requires using
>   a getter function around a private variable (with no corresponding
>   "dumb" setter). And once you have getter functions for some fields it
>   just looks weird to have other fields be public. This again isn't a
>   problem for TypeScript, because it *does* have read-only public
>   fields.
>
> The final argument for getters/setters in a language like C++ is that
>   there *might* someday be a change required to a setter to enforce a
>   constraint, but it would be a source-breaking change to make a public
>   field become private, so the code might as well just use
>   getters/setters from the start for "forward compatibility." This again
>   isn't a problem for JS/TS because property setters exist, so you can
>   evolve code and strengthen constraint checking without source breaking
>   changes even without setter functions.

Comment: Emiliano por favor traduce ese texto o sacalo. La finalidad del sitio es que todo este en español.

Answer (score 2):

¡Es una muy buena pregunta!

Typescript es un lenguaje creado por Microsoft, pero sorprendentemente se parece en muchos detalles más a Java que a C#

Esto, que puede parecer poco importante, ha ayudado a popularizar mucho Angular, un framework creado por Google y que ha usado Typescript para implementarlo. Pero no sólo eso, Angular está pensado para parecerse mucho a una aplicación hecha con Java: Puedes *anotar* clases, método y atributos con decoradores o *anotaciones*, que son clases/funciones con una @ delante, por ejemplo. Esto se usa para la inyección de dependencias al estilo de Spring...

*¿Qué tiene todo ésto que ver con los getters y setters?*

Pues tiene que ver porque crear métodos como los que has expuesto en tu ejemplo es totalmente innecesario en Javascript:

```js
class Ejemplo {

  constructor(dato) {
    this._dato=dato
  }
 
  get dato() {
    return this._dato;
  }
 
  set dato(valor) {
    this._dato=`Guardado ${valor}`;
  }
}

const e= new Ejemplo('Hola');

console.log('El atributo no es realmente privado:',e._dato);
console.log('Pero tiene un getter:', e.dato);

e.dato='esto';

console.log('Y un setter:', e.dato);
```

Javascript tiene su propia forma de crear getters y setters, similar a C#. Y puesto que todo Javascript válido es también Typescript válido (TS es un **superconjunto** de JS), podrías usar esas mismas opciones.

Pero mucha gente que usa Typescript viene de Java (yo mismo, por ejemplo), donde no existe esta sintaxis y el usar getters y setters es una convención muy extendida. Por tanto, si aprendes Typescript viniendo de Java y para aprender Angular, es normal que importes todas la convenciones de Java a este lenguaje.

Explicado esto, también hay que hacer notar otro detalle: Las palabras `public`y `private` de Typescript son como los genéricos en Java: no sobreviven al compilador. Es decir, los atributos privados que intentes usar fuera de la clase provocarán un error en el compilador de Typescript, pero una vez hayas generado el código Javascript, otro código podría usar tus clases accediendo directamente a los métodos y atributos supuestamente privados de las mismas porque **en Javascript no hay modificadores de acceso** [de momento](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

### Conclusión

Javascript no obliga a usar getters y setters, Typescript por tanto tampoco... pero puedes usarlos si te parece apropiado (asegurarte de que los valores obtenidos/devueltos son válidos, por ejemplo).

Personalmente no los suelo usar porque no me aportan nada (no implemento librerías para terceros donde el API tenga que ser especiamente limpia), pero en algunos casos excepcionales uso la sintaxis get/set mostrada arriba para crearlos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que ésta, más que una recomendación para Typescript, es una recomendación para cualquier lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos.

Como ha comentado x-rw (a quién creo que se le debe un par de votos positivos a los comentarios de esta pregunta), aunque Typescript sea un lenguaje que posterirormente sea compilado a Javascript, Typescript sigue siendo un lenguaje POO desde el momento en el que permite:

· La creación de clases e interfaces.

· La encapsulación.

· La abstracción de clases.

· La herencia de clases y la implementación de interfaces.

· El poliformismo.

El proceso de compilación debería ser independiente al planteamiento de la programación en el lenguaje. C++ se puede compilar dando lugar a código ensamblador (me refiero a compilaciones puras, no las que usa .Net que genera código intermedio CIL). El hecho de que ensamblador no sea orientado a objetos no quiere decir que no sean aplicables las buenas prácticas de los lenguajes POO a C++.

¿Pero por qué es bueno usar getters y setters?

1. Permiten controlar el acceso a un atributo de instancia cuyo acceso podría querer controlarse. Podrías querer que un campo de tipo number solo contenga números enteros, y el setter sería un gran sitio en el que implementar ese control. De esta forma, la gestión del atributo debe hacerse mediante el getter y el setter.
2. Aumenta la mantenibilidad del código. El mundo del software está lleno de cambios. El desarrollo de un proyecto software suele convertirse en un ciclo de análisis, diseño, implementación y pruebas de la aplicación. El primer ciclo trata la definición inicial del software a desarrollar, pero casi siempre el cliente suele cambiar de opinión, o hay malentendidos entre clientes y analistas, o entre analistas e implementadores y hay que rediseñar parte del sistema. El usar getters y setters aunque en principio no sea necesario permite que la implementación del control de ese atributo se haga en dos únicos métodos: el getter y el setter, evitando tener que cambiar cada acceso al atributo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

## No deben usarse getters y setters a menos que los necesites

La gran ventaja de los lenguajes como Typescript (y Javascript), es que no necesitan programar getters y setters salvo que en algún momento realmente los necesites. Y en ese momento no hay que cambiar el código por todos lados para usarlo.

Por ejemplo si tienes la clase `persona`:

```
class Persona{
    nombre:string
    edad:number
}

var persona = new Persona();

persona.nombre = 'Emilio';
persona.edad = 49;
console.log(persona);
```

Luego decides que no quieres que por se asigne una edad negativa a una persona 
(quieres lanzar una excepción en ese caso), entonces es el momento de poner un setter que haga el control:

```
class Persona{
    private _edad: number;
    nombre: string
    get edad() {
        return this._edad
    }
    set edad(value: number) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new Error("Edad inválida (negativa)");
        }
        this._edad = value;
    }
}

var delfuturo = new Persona();
delfuturo.nombre = 'Futurux';
delfuturo.edad = -10;
console.log(delfuturo);
```

En el ejemplo se ve un getter que solo devuelve el valor privado y un setter que hace el control. 
Solo tuvimos que cambiar la clase. 
Todos los demás lugares donde se usaba un objeto de clase persona quedan sin cambio 
aún cuando se haya pasado de usar miembros a getter y setter. 
Por eso no es necesario hacerlo desde un principio.

```
function esMayor(persona){
    return persona.edad >= 18;
}
```

Ahora supongamos que queremos separar los nombres de los apellidos. 
Ahí sí vamos a tener que cambiar en todos los lugares que se asigne el "nombre" 
habrá que hacer la inserción por separado 
(dado que no hay manera cierta de hacerlo, aún con un diccionario porque hay apellidos que también son nombres).

Pero se pueden dejar como están los lugares donde se usa el "nombre" como el texto nombres y apellidos 
(si es que ese era el valor que se estaba usando).

Por ejemplo

```
class Persona{
    private _edad: number;
    nombres: string
    apellidos: string
    get nombre() {
        return this.nombres + ' ' + this.apellidos;
    }
    get edad() {
        return this._edad
    }
    set edad(value: number) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new Error("Edad inválida (negativa)");
        }
        this._edad = value;
    }
}

var maradona = new Persona();
/* Daría error de compilación:
   maradona.nombre = 'Diego Armando Maradona';
*/ 
/* Daría error de ejecución:
   maradona.edad = -1;
*/ 
maradona.nombres = 'Diego Armando';
maradona.apellidos = 'Maradona'
maradona.edad = 58;
console.log(maradona);

function bienvenida(persona) {
    alert('Le damos la bienvenida a ' + persona.nombre);
}

bienvenida(maradona);
```

El getter permite calcular el valor que antes tenía el campo `nombre` y seguir usando sin modificar las funciones que lo usaban sin setearlo.

Ver en: 
[ejemplo de typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Persona%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_edad%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20nombres%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20apellidos%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20nombre()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.nombres%20%2B%20'%20'%20%2B%20this.apellidos%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20edad()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._edad%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20edad(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(value%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22Edad%20inv%C3%A1lida%20(negativa)%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._edad%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20maradona%20%3D%20new%20Persona()%3B%0D%0A%2F*%20Dar%C3%ADa%20error%20de%20compilaci%C3%B3n%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20maradona.nombre%20%3D%20'Diego%20Armando%20Maradona'%3B%0D%0A*%2F%20%0D%0A%2F*%20Dar%C3%ADa%20error%20de%20ejecuci%C3%B3n%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20maradona.edad%20%3D%20-1%3B%0D%0A*%2F%20%0D%0Amaradona.nombres%20%3D%20'Diego%20Armando'%3B%0D%0Amaradona.apellidos%20%3D%20'Maradona'%0D%0Amaradona.edad%20%3D%2058%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(maradona)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bienvenida(persona)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert('Le%20damos%20la%20bienvenida%20a%20'%20%2B%20persona.nombre)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Abienvenida(maradona)%3B)